# How to split a list of dictionaries into multiple columns keeping the same index?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a data frame that has as index a timestamp and a column that has list of dictionaries:

```
    index                   var_A

    2019-08-21 09:05:49    [{"Date1": "Aug 21, 2017 9:09:51 AM","Date2": "Aug 21, 2017 9:09:54 AM","Id": "d5e665e5","num_ins": 108,"num_del": 0, "time": 356} , {"Date1": "Aug 21, 2017 9:09:57 AM","Date2": "Aug 21, 2017 9:09:59 AM","Id": "d5e665e5","num_ins": 218,"num_del": 5, "time": 166}]
    2019-08-21 09:05:59    [{"Date1": "Aug 21, 2017 9:10:01 AM","Date2": "Aug 21, 2017 9:11:54 AM","Id": "d5e665e5","num_ins": 348,"num_del": 72, "time": 3356} , {"Date1": "Aug 21, 2017 9:19:57 AM","Date2": "Aug 21, 2017 9:19:59 AM","Id": "d5e665e5","num_ins": 69,"num_del": 5, "time": 125}, {"Date1": "Aug 21, 2017 9:20:01 AM","Date2": "Aug 21, 2017 9:21:54 AM","Id": "f9e775f9","num_ins": 470,"num_del": 0, "time": 290} ]
    2019-08-21 09:06:04    []
```

What I wish to achieve is a dataframe like:

```
    index              Date1                      Date2                    Id      num_ins       num_del    time
2019-08-21 09:05:49   Aug 21, 2017 9:09:51AM   Aug 21, 2017 9:09:54AM   d5e665e5      0           108        356
2019-08-21 09:05:49   Aug 21, 2017 9:09:57AM   Aug 21, 2017 9:09:59AM   d5e665e5      218           5        166
2019-08-21 09:05:59   Aug 21, 2017 9:10:01AM   Aug 21, 2017 9:11:54AM   d5e665e5      348          72       3356
2019-08-21 09:05:59   Aug 21, 2017 9:19:57AM   Aug 21, 2017 9:19:59AM   d5e665e5      69            5        125
2019-08-21 09:05:59   Aug 21, 2017 9:20:01AM   Aug 21, 2017 9:21:54AM   f9e775f9      470           0        290
2019-08-21 09:06:04     NAN                         NAN                    NAN        NAN         NAN        NAN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop by each value with `enumerate`, because duplicated inex values and create `DataFrame`s, then create DataFrame for empty lists and last `concat` together:

```
import ast

out = {}
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(df['var_A'].items()):
    df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    if df.empty:
        out[(i, k)] = pd.DataFrame(index=[0], columns=['Id'])
    else:
        out[(i, k)] = df

df = pd.concat(out, sort=True).reset_index(level=[0,2], drop=True)
print (df)
                                       Date1                    Date2  \
2019-08-21 09:05:49  Aug 21, 2017 9:09:51 AM  Aug 21, 2017 9:09:54 AM   
2019-08-21 09:05:49  Aug 21, 2017 9:09:57 AM  Aug 21, 2017 9:09:59 AM   
2019-08-21 09:05:59  Aug 21, 2017 9:10:01 AM  Aug 21, 2017 9:11:54 AM   
2019-08-21 09:05:59  Aug 21, 2017 9:19:57 AM  Aug 21, 2017 9:19:59 AM   
2019-08-21 09:05:59  Aug 21, 2017 9:20:01 AM  Aug 21, 2017 9:21:54 AM   
2019-08-21 09:05:59                      NaN                      NaN   

                           Id  num_del  num_ins    time  
2019-08-21 09:05:49  d5e665e5      0.0    108.0   356.0  
2019-08-21 09:05:49  d5e665e5      5.0    218.0   166.0  
2019-08-21 09:05:59  d5e665e5     72.0    348.0  3356.0  
2019-08-21 09:05:59  d5e665e5      5.0     69.0   125.0  
2019-08-21 09:05:59  f9e775f9      0.0    470.0   290.0  
2019-08-21 09:05:59       NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am still getting an error. I actually had a typo in my post. My original indexes are unique. I don't know if this could be affecting. But the error says: malformed node or string:

Comment: @jessirocha - What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'var_A']))` ?

Comment: @jessirocha - if it return list, then change `df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(v))` to `df = pd.DataFrame(v)`

Comment: I can't print it: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [0] of <class 'int'>

Comment: @jessirocha - And `print (type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'var_A']))` ?

Comment: It works! Before it must have been a bug. It returned a list and I replaced by df = pd.DataFrame(v) as suggested. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` functions `stack` and `concat` to do this.

1. First use `stack` to unlist the list the column `var_A`
2. Then use `concat` to unnest the dictionary and put it into seperate columns

You can use the following code to do the same. Assuming your dictionary to be df.

Unlist:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)
```

[image]

Unnest:

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('var_A', axis=1), df['var_A'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).drop(0,1)
```

[image]